# Reading & writing data to a .txt file using vscode extension api

Tags: file, visual-studio-code, fs, vscode-extensions

So I am new to this vscode extension api. I have this functionality where I need to take input from the user when they click on certain line and then get the `1). input value, line number and file name` and `2). store it to a text file`.

I am done with the first part, I am getting the data everything. Now I have to just write it to the file and if there is data already, new data should be appended not overwritten.

I have tried using `fs.writeFileSync(filePath, data) and readFileSync` but nothing, I do not know if I am doing it correctly. If someone can point me in the right direction I am just blank at this stage?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include code that shows what you tried and explain what you mean by "I have tried... but nothing".

Answer (score 0):

The FS node module works fine in an extension. I use it all the time for file work in [my extension](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/frontend/Utils.ts). Here's a helper function to export something to a file with error handling:

```
/**
 * Asks the user for a file to store the given data in. Checks if the file already exists and ask for permission to
 * overwrite it, if so. Also copies a number extra files to the target folder.
 *
 * @param fileName A default file name the user can change, if wanted.
 * @param filter The file type filter as used in showSaveDialog.
 * @param data The data to write.
 * @param extraFiles Files to copy to the target folder (e.g. css).
 */
public static exportDataWithConfirmation(fileName: string, filters: { [name: string]: string[] }, data: string,
    extraFiles: string[]): void {
    void window.showSaveDialog({
        defaultUri: Uri.file(fileName),
        filters,
    }).then((uri: Uri | undefined) => {
        if (uri) {
            const value = uri.fsPath;
            fs.writeFile(value, data, (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    void window.showErrorMessage("Could not write to file: " + value + ": " + error.message);
                } else {
                    this.copyFilesIfNewer(extraFiles, path.dirname(value));
                    void window.showInformationMessage("Diagram successfully written to file '" + value + "'.");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And here an example where I [read a file without user intervention](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/frontend/AntlrDebugAdapter.ts#L210):

```
    this.configurationDone.wait(1000).then(() => {
        ...
        try {
            const testInput = fs.readFileSync(args.input, { encoding: "utf8" });
            ...

        } catch (e) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    });
```